# I need to Add a Custom Customer Attribute it should be visible in admin panel and should save in database

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute

How can Achieve creating Custom Customer Attribute that should be visible in customer page of admin panel how can I create can anyone help me out

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 1.9.2.4  version

Answer (score 1):

app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php $installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer'); $attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId); $attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Custom Attribute"

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'customattribute',
    '999'  //sort_order );

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer"; //$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register"; //$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create"; //$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit"; //$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
        <global>

            <resources>
                <Your_Customattribute_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_setup>
                <Your_Customattribute_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_write>
                <Your_Customattribute_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_read>
            </resources>
        </global>

    </config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Your_Customattribute.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Then to retrieve or edit you use:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
$customer->setCustomattribute($yourjson);
```

Comment: i tried But i'm unable to get proper output,the attribute is not showing at admin panel

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$installer = $this;
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Is Active',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'default' => '0',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'used_in_forms' => array(
        'adminhtml_customer',
    ),
    'comment' => 'Flag to check if user can log into their account. 0 = No, 1 = Yes.',
); 

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in', $attribute);

 Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

if you want to add it in all the place use below

```
> Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
>         ->getAttribute('customer', 'can_log_in')
>     ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
>     ->save();
```

Comment: why did you add your answers as two answers? beter to put at one place. then that may be helpful.